# How to select all tables on the page unless they contain a row with a specific class

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble finding the correct selector combination to select:

- any tables on the page
- containing thead and tbody
- with no rows with the class 'no-results'

**Sample Table with class**

```
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
             <th class="highlight">Name</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Manage</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="no-results">
                    <td class="solo" colspan="4">
                        No <b>mail templates</b> found! <a>Create New Template</a>
                    </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried:

`$("table:has(thead ~ tbody tr:not([class='no-results'])");`

Comment: I finally came up with a winner!!
```
var tables = $("table:has(thead ~ tbody>tr:not('.no-results'))"); // non-empty tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it will select a table that does not contains `.no-results` class. I hope this works.

```
 $("table:not(.no-results)")
```

Comment: I only want table that do not have the .no-results

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a winner!!

```
var tables = $("table:has(thead ~ tbody>tr:not('.no-results'))"); // non-empty tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :not(X) selector.

Ref - https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation .